# Pipelining to get certain data

Tags: bash, shell, awk, pipelining

I have a command that gives the following output:

```
#sec one
a : same
b : red
c : one
d :
e :
f :

#sec two
a : same
b : blue
c : two
d :
e :

#sec three
a : different
b : green
c : three
d :
e :

#sec four
a : different
b : yellow
c : four

#sec five
a : different
b : pink
c : five
```

There are a lot of such sections. I need only the sections that have `a : same` and the value of `b` and `c` fields for those sections.

Sample output:

```
#sec one
a : same
b : red
c : one


#sec two
a : same
b : blue
c : two
```

This is what I've done so far!
Tr -s to make it equally spaced.

```
mycommand | tr -s " " | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

Does anyone know another way of doing it or using conditionals in cut statements?

Comment: I would suggest doing this sort of structured parsing in a language other than Bash. It's probably doable, but it's going to be a pain. Try Python, if you've never used it before it'll be a fun exercise.

Comment: Can't be done using awk as well?

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely trivial with awk. Do you want the b and c sections printed because they start with the letters b and c or because they are non-empty on the right of the `:`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `awk` can help you here ;) Try this:

```
mycommand | tr -d " " | awk -F: '/a:/ {a=$2;} /(b:|c:)/ {if (a == "same") print $2;}'
```

output:

```
red
one
blue
two
```

If you need the field *names* as well, just replace `$2` with `$0` in the last `print`:

```
mycommand | tr -d " " | awk -F: '/a:/ {a=$2;} /(b:|c:)/ {if (a == "same") print $0;}'
```

output:

```
b:red
c:one
b:blue
c:two
```

By the way, tested on *macOS 10.12.4* running `awk` version `20070501`.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= -F'\n' '/a : same/{print $1; 
                                for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i~/^(a|b|c)/) print $i; 
                                print ""}' file    

#sec one                                                                                                                                  
a : same                                                                                                                                  
b : red                                                                                                                                   
c : one                                                                                                                                   

#sec two                                                                                                                                  
a : same                                                                                                                                  
b : blue                                                                                                                                  
c : two
```

Answer (score 0):

I find when you have name->value pairs in your input it's best to first create an array that represents that mapping and then you can get at field values by just using their names, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n" }
{
    delete n2v
    for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {
        name = value = $i
        sub(/[[:space:]]*:.*/,"",name)
        sub(/^[^:]+:[[:space:]]*/,"",value)
        n2v[name] = value
    }
}
n2v["a"] == "same" { print $1, p("a"), p("b"), p("c") }
function p(n) { return (n " : " n2v[n]) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
#sec one
a : same
b : red
c : one

#sec two
a : same
b : blue
c : two
```

That way you can trivially and robustly modify your script to print whatever fields you want for whatever reasons you want in whatever order you want by just tweaking the last 2 lines of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Two one-liners:

1. *GNU* `grep` method:

   ```
   grep --group-separator= -B1 -A2 '^a : same$' input_file
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   #sec one
   a : same
   b : red
   c : one

   #sec two
   a : same
   b : blue
   c : two
   ```
2. A little buffer juggling with `sed`:

   ```
   sed -n '/^a : same$/{x;p;x;p;n;p;n;p;z;p};h' input_file
   ```

   Output:

   ```
   #sec one
   a : same
   b : red
   c : one

   #sec two
   a : same
   b : blue
   c : two
   ```

   ---

   How it works:

   - `/^a : same$/` finds the section to print, but it's never the first
     line, (there's always a preceding comment line), so the first code
     that's executed is `h`, which overwrites whatever's in the "*hold*"
     buffer with the current line.
   - So the next cycle, the *hold* buffer always contains the previous
        line, and the *pattern* buffer contains the current line.
   - When `/^a : same$/` is true, the code in curly braces is run.  It    e`x`changes the *pattern* and *hold* buffers, `p`rints what was in
     the *hold* buffer, (*i.e.* the comment line), e`x`changes them back,
     `p`rints the *pattern* buffer, (*i.e.* the search string), twice it
     gets the    `n`ext line and `p`rints it, after that it `z`aps the
     *pattern* buffer, (deletes it),    and `p`rints that, (*i.e.* prints a blank line).